# Intellij IDEA not showing full javadoc in small window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I remember that it was possible to see full javadoc in little window on hotkey in Eclipse some time ago (I used Eclipse Java two years ago). How can I see *full* javadoc in Intellij IDEA via hotkeys (Ctlr+Q of course, because I am using Ubuntu) or/and on mouse over? I see only function parameters and specified class information that I know, but I want to see a lot of description text from real [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). I mean that small window with javadoc should contain this:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>
> In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function...

... etc. But I don't see this content.

[image: Intellij IDEA javadoc not showing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you ended up with JDK sources removed from your project. To resolve the issue go to Project Settings > Platform Settings > SDK > Sourcepath, navigate to your JDK installation and add its `src.zip` to the project.

Use the following image as a reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think it should help me, but I don't have src.zip in my jdk's folder. Where can I find it? I am using IDEA jbr instead of JDK. And I see there are "Documentation Paths" bar. Do I must to configure it too?

Comment: I've just downloaded `src.zip` from OpenJDK, but I can't move it to my JDK's path even with `sudo`. JDK path is `/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/198/jbr` (OS Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `Ctrl`+`Q`+`Q`?

---

Also note that you can add `{@inheritDoc}` for inheriting JavaDoc to the overridden methods. Something like:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public int compare(Circle c1, Circle c2)
```

Comment: Doesn't it do that automatically when there is no Javadoc comment at all? So it only makes sense if you add something before or after the {@inheritDoc}.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't helped me. `Ctrl` + `Q` + `Q` is only enrarges small window at the right side of IDEA, but it still doestn't contain normal documentation that I told in my question.